# Assign a function with universal argument to a key (org-timer-start)

Tags: key-bindings, prefix-argument

I would like to assing the function `org-timer-start` with a univeral argument (`Ctrl-u`) to its own key.

I read [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/14748/how-to-bind-a-command-with-a-c-u-prefix-to-a-different-key), that one should look into the source code of a function to find out how to pass a universal argument.

Where is this part in the following function, that tells me about the universal argument call?

```lisp
    (defun org-timer-start (&optional offset)
      "Set the starting time for the relative timer to now.
    When called with prefix argument OFFSET, prompt the user for an offset time,
    with the default taken from a timer stamp at point, if any.
    If OFFSET is a string or an integer, it is directly taken to be the offset
    without user interaction.
    When called with a double prefix arg, all timer strings in the active
    region will be shifted by a specific amount.  You will be prompted for
    the amount, with the default to make the first timer string in
    the region 0:00:00."
      (interactive "P")
      (cond
       ((equal offset '(16))
        (call-interactively 'org-timer-change-times-in-region))
       (org-timer-countdown-timer
        (user-error "Countdown timer is running.  Cancel first"))
       (t
        (let (delta def s)
          (if (not offset)
          (setq org-timer-start-time (current-time))
        (cond
         ((integerp offset) (setq delta offset))
         ((stringp offset) (setq delta (org-timer-hms-to-secs offset)))
         (t
          (setq def (if (org-in-regexp org-timer-re)
                (match-string 0)
                  "0:00:00")
            s (read-string
               (format "Restart timer with offset [%s]: " def)))
          (unless (string-match "\\S-" s) (setq s def))
          (setq delta (org-timer-hms-to-secs (org-timer-fix-incomplete s)))))
        (setq org-timer-start-time (org-time-since delta)))
          (setq org-timer-pause-time nil)
          (org-timer-set-mode-line 'on)
          (message "Timer start time set to %s, current value is %s"
               (format-time-string "%T" org-timer-start-time)
               (org-timer-secs-to-hms (or delta 0)))
          (run-hooks 'org-timer-start-hook)))))
```

Do I need to make a custom fuction to call org-timer-start with a `Ctrl-u` prefix?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to apply \`call-interactively\` to an interactive command that accepts the universal argument?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/21626/how-to-apply-call-interactively-to-an-interactive-command-that-accepts-the-uni)

Comment: I wasn't going to take the time to look for the duplicate, but a quick search of `[prefix-argument]` found it.

Comment: It's hard to tell if yes or no with my little experience, but I tend to no, because it does not anser `Where is this part in the following function, that tells me about the universal argument call?` and I think it does not anser `Do I need to make a custom fuction to call org-timer-start with a Ctrl-u prefix?`. But honestly I don't really understand enough to assert.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The part you need to look at is the interactive declaration which in this case is `(interactive "P")`. This means that `C-u` is passing the argument `(4)` to `org-timer-start`. So you need to assign the lambda

```lisp
(lambda ()
  (interactive)
  (org-timer-start '(4)))
```

to a key in whatever keymap you want that will be active when you want to use it. The keymap you should probably choose is the one where `org-timer-start` is bound. You also need to make this binding after the keymap has been defined as a variable.

It seems that `org-timer-start` is not bound to any key by default and that the function is loaded when `org-mode` is loaded so it would be sensible to bind this lambda in `org-mode-map` as part of your customisation of `org-mode`.

Comment: Does this mean I would use something like `(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "C-c N") (lambda () (interactive)(org-timer-start '(4)))` ?

Comment: Yes, that should work

Comment: To define it as a new function I used `(defun org-timer-start-with-offset ()
  "Start the timer and prompt user to enter a time offset"
    (interactive)
    (org-timer-start '(4)))`